# Springs BeanUtils.copyProperties() vs Apache Commons BeanUtils.copyProperties

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-beanutils, spring-framework-beans

Trying to do something simple here. Take an Entity object and copy it's identically named properties to another bean.

You can do this with Apache commons

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(source,target)
```

but the issue here is that we may have some properties that are specific to the entity bean (metadata like created,lastUpdated, etc timestamps) that we don't want to copy to the target bean and Apache Commons BeanUtils does not support ignoring of properties. I was pushed in the direction of Spring BeanUtils

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(source,target,ignoreProperties)
```

Where ignoreProperties is an array of strings of the property name syou want to ignore. Now the issue seems to be when performing this property copy it nulls the properties of the source object! As the source object is an Entity object with a mandatory id field when the transaction is committed we  get a HibernateException

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance {source} was altered from {originalId} to null
```

Anyone know a way around this or are you committed to using one or the other? Confusing to me why the commons librariy doesn't support ignoring properties while copying or why the springframework BeanUtils seems to perform a cut/paste instead of a copy/paste.

Comment: According to [Spring source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.java#L670), what you are saying is not the case: ignored properties are, indeed, ignored. You need to search for the problem elsewhere.

Comment: I didn't say that they were, read the question again. What I said happens is that source Object's property fields are cut and pasted rather than copy and pasted, which means the fields in the source object are set to null, which when it's an entity object causes issues when the transaction is committed.

Comment: It is, again, not the problem of Spring implementation. It can only happen if your code nulls out the property when a getter is invoked.

Comment: Just realised the issue here, Apache uses (target, source), Springframework uses (source, target), doh.

Comment: great answer. simple difference.

Comment: Also, when using Spring BeanUtils you dont need to do an explicit try/catch or handle throws which you have to do when you are using BeanUtils from Apache package so +1 to Spring BeanUtils